# WSO2IS - Assigning Roles to "Teams"

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I guess this is a two part question.

1. Is there a concept of "Teams" or "User Groups" in WSO2IS?
2. Can roles be assigned to the concept described in 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WSO2 IS there is no separate concept for "user groups". But "roles" are essentially the same thing. You can define a role to represent a certain group of people and assign it to all the people that belong to that group. In addition to that you can associate permissions with that role. For more information on this please refer [User Management Architecture](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/User+Management+Architecture).